# How can I match multiple sets of a regular expression pattern in the same string?

Tags: regex, whitespace

I am building a regex against strings that meet the following requirements:

1. The string has a maximum of 5 sets of alphanumeric characters.
2. Each set within the string is separated by SINGLE whitespace character.

For example, we can have "asa22d asdcac3" or "Asdcd234 sacasW2 sas1 s sd1" (hopefully you get the picture). So far I have:

```
^[A-z 0-9]\s{0,1}
```

I am not using `\w` because it allows underscores. This works for one set of characters, but I need to allow five sets of the same sort of strings separated by a space.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what language you are using, but this should do it for you:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(\s[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,4}$
```

A word, followed by up to four instances of space-then-word.

Comment: Thank you very much!! this works perfectly. Could you please also 'translate' this expression in English...or point me towards some good regex tutorial?

Comment: Best regex testing and learning site I have ever encountered: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

#### Tools You Need

To match multiple instances of a pattern in a regular expression, you can use any combination of match groups, backreferences, and interval expressions allowed by your regular expression engine.

#### Examples

Based on your sample code, your regular expression engine clearly supports intervals, so use that. Here are two examples that will accomplish the goal.

```
# Use POSIX character classes with an interval expression
^([[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]?){1,5}$

# PCRE expression with intervals
\A(\p{Xan}+\s?){1,5}\Z
```